# Track iOS UIWebView memory consumption

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, uiwebview

We are working on HTML5 application - it consists of single WebView and some native parts.
But there is a huge memory leak(memory warnings and then crash) and we don't know if that WebView or native part...

So is there any way to track memory consumption by UIWebView or track object allocations to find who is leaking - WebView or native parts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your application in Xcode with the Profiler tool (command - I). In this, you are able to use a number of different tools to track memory allocations, leaks, zombies, etc..

Additionally, when profiling system resource utilization, I recommend you do all of this testing on a real device to ensure accuracy.

[image]